# Python Selenium "name 'driver' is not defined"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, error-handling, webdriver

I'm trying to log into an account of mine using Selenium on with python. When I write this code without object it works with no problems, but when I start to implement a class I get the error:

```
name 'driver' not defined
```

It' weird because before I get the error 'driver' is already called 1 time.

The code looks like this:

```
class my_bot:
def __init__(self):

    self.driver = webdriver.Safari()
    self.driver.get('https://website.com')

def login(self, email, password):

    self.email = email
    self.password = password

    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)

    fb_btn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="modal-manager"]/div/div/div/div/div[3]/span/div[2]/button')))
    self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()", fb_btn)
    sleep(3)

    #switch the window

    base_window = self.driver.window_handles[0]
    self.driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
```

I get the error on the last line even though the call of 'driver' already happened before.

Has anyone an idea why this isnt working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code while switching to new window. it will help you to get the window handle after a new window has opened

```
self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

add self.

self.driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[1])
-> self.driver.switch_to_window(self.driver.window_handles[1])